# Show additional lines that are not part of the file

Tags: code-folding

What I want is the opposite of code folding. Code folding looks like this:

```
Unfolded:
1 * Top Level
2 ** Second Level
3 Info that belongs to Second Level
4 More Info that belongs to Second Level
5 ** Another Second Level
6 More Info

Folded (usually with a "..." at the end of Second Level):
1 * Top Level
2 ** Second Level
5 ** Another Second Level
6 More Info
```

What I want looks like this:

```
Unexpanded:
1 * Top Level
2 ** Second Level
3 Info that belongs to Second Level [Expandable]
4 More Info that belongs to Second Level
5 ** Another Second Level
6 More Info

Expanded:
1 * Top Level
2 ** Second Level
3 Info that belongs to Second Level [Expandable]
  Additional info
  More additional info
4 More Info that belongs to Second Level
5 ** Another Second Level
6 More Info
```

The main idea is that I don't want the additional information to be part of the actual file. The information is sourced from elsewhere. How can I inject these pseudolines into my buffers?

Comment: You can certainly add an [overlay](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Overlay-Properties.html)... But I doubt whether there's existing extension to satify your specific need as your request looks very broad.

Comment: `org-mode` supports including files when exporting, but not as a code-folding option.  The question is in the nature of a feature request.  Implementation of this new feature is most likely beyond the scope of what forum participants normally answer, but perhaps the original poster will be lucky in enticing someone motivated.  I would suggest that the original poster look into maximizing the `*Org Agenda*` abilities that can take bits and pieces from various files and assemble the results into one buffer.  See:  `org-tags-view`, `org-search-view`, and `org-agenda-list`.